# Understanding the Api in PHP

Tags: php, api

a beginner here.

I have already checked the forum to find out answers but I was not successful, my question is specifically on one line of code. So I hope no one will mark my question as duplicate as I am in learning curve. 2 problems here:

- What is the meaning of this piece of code? I understand that it is making a new object but is `Api` a reserved word? What is `none` for? `$user = new Api('none','none');`
- I understand what is API but could you please introduce any good resource that explains the API for beginners? I do not fully understand the concept of APIs.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: In that code when instantiating a new object from the Api class you pass two parameters (2x string 'none') to the constructor of the class. Check out the __construct method inside the class Api to see what it's used for.

Comment: There is no *“the API”*. An API is a set of functionality which has the purpose of providing access to some component, without knowing the internals of that component. A common use case are *web-service APIs* (e.g. JSON-based over HTTP). But, in any case, you must tell us what specific API you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Api is not a reserved keyword in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php)

This is simply creating a new instance of `Api`, which should be somewhere in your codebase or include path. Look at it's constructor to find out why those parameters are passed.

Also, being a beginner does not excuse you for posting duplicate questions ;)

Comment: @DNM, thank you for the answer, I found the constructor. And by the way I made sure this question was not duplicate before I posted it, so there was no excuse :D